# Dagger does not support injection into private fields

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2, android-viewmodel

I have next `viewModel`:

```
class AnyViewModel(app: App) : AndroidViewModel(app) {
    @Inject private lateinit var repository: AnyRepository
    @Inject private lateinit var api: AnyApi

    init {
        app.appComponent.injectAnyViewModel(this)
    }
```

Build returns error in the title

How does I can to avoid that error and keep variables private?

Comment: You can't use field injections with private fields. Use contructor injection or remove private modificator

Comment: Well yeah, it doesn't. You can make them `internal` if you want, or `public`. In Java, you'd be able to make them package-private, but that's not a thing in Kotlin. Actually, you could probably also use `protected`.